# How to make a raspberry pi "hot unpluggable"

Tags: sd-card, power, corrupt

I want to be able to just pull the power on my raspberry pi project.

I am aware that sd cards don't like that. Is it possible to use some kind of other persistent storage such as a flash drive or some kind of sd card adapter that would allow me to be able to just unplug the power without worrying about data corruption, as is the case with the pico for example?

Comment: If you pull the power on any computer you risk corruption. Most expensive computers have circuitry to gracefully shut down (which costs more than a Pi). It is possible to add such hardware to a Pi. Frankly the risk of corruption on a Pi is greatly exaggerated. Over 10 years with more power failures than I can remember I have never corrupted an SD Card. I often have to cut power. SD do wear out and operator error is more likely to corrupt OS.

Comment: @Milliways well that is quite surprising to me. We're using a raspberry pi in a commercial product and after a few years we hardly have any units that haven't had their sd card corrupted due to mains power outages.

Comment: @php_nub_qq I am the same and concur. Millways does not know what he is talking about

Comment: @php_nub_qq I use a UPS. Never had any problems since.

Comment: My experience is much the same as Milliways.  However, while I've had least one Pi running 24/7 during 95% of that decade, none of the applications I've put them to required continuous high volume writing to the SD card, which I think is a factor (ie., it would increase the chance of corruption if the power suddenly dies).   Also, my power cuts aren't all that frequent.

Comment: ...Worth noting, though, that these events are partially conjecture; just because it doesn't work when the power comes back does not mean the SD card was corrupted by the power fail.  We certainly get people here who aren't deploying numbers of Pi commercially or doing anything particularly unusual but seem to be cursed with SD  corruption problems for whatever strange reason -- IMO a toss up between hardware malfunction and unrecognized user error.

Comment: I gather you can set Raspberry Pi OS to be read only. Don't know the implications of this nor what your project requires.

Comment: @CoderMike I've read in another question which I can't find now, that it doesn't matter how the partition is mounted, the way SD cards work data can even get corrupted on unmounted partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make the entire RPi "hot unpluggable" by dealing only with the SD card.

You're (presumably) using the **ext4** filesystem; this ***helps*** prevent corruption on your SD card because it's a [*journaled* filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system). But it can't do the job by itself. If the processor loses power it can't complete all of the filesystem chores it may be involved in executing.

This realization leads us to next consider an **Uninterrubtible Power Supply**, which may get you closer to what you seem to be after. There are commercially-available UPS "HATS" available ([for example](https://geekworm.com/collections/raspberry-pi-ups/products/raspberry-pi-x728-max-5-1v-8a-18650-ups-power-management-board)) that may serve your needs. Since these are usually battery-powered, you may wish to add software logic and/or additional hardware to terminate (`halt`) RPi processing, and then power down the UPS and RPi to avoid exhausing batteries.

Your "hot unpluggable" idea is interesting, and not without applications, but it will require some effort to realize it.